# Easy way of drawing 'All Borders' in tables?

Tags: tables, border

I'm currently drawing borders like so:

```
begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
 \hline
 a & b & c \\
 \hline
 d & e & f \\
 \hline
 g & i & j \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
```

However, this requires a `\hline` between every row. Is there a concise, and preferable native, method of drawing all borders?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you by making your code example compilable (a MWE).

Comment: By native, I assume you mean still using `tabular`? If you are open to using a different table environment, you can use `tabu` with `\everyrow{\hline}`.

Comment: @TeXnician By compilable, do you mean to include the \documentclass, \begin{document} and \end{document} sections?

Comment: @DavidPurton I just realised that `tabular` can be quite limited, so yes, I am considering different environments. I'll have a look

Comment: @GeorgeTian Off-topic, but such a data-prison style for your tables might not be the best choice. Please have a look at http://betterposters.blogspot.com/2012/08/the-data-prison.html

Comment: @samcarter Thank you. I have realised this, and will be removing quite a few lines from my tables :)

Comment: @GeorgeTian https://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/markusp/teaching/guides/guide-tables.pdf provides a short example how to produce nice looking tables in latex.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatically creating table with borders](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512053/automatically-creating-table-with-borders)

Answer (score 4):

Since you say you are open to using a different table environment, try `tabu`. It has many options including `\everyrow{}`, which can be used to insert lines at every row.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\begin{document}
\everyrow{\hline}
\begin{tabu}{|c|c|c|}
  a & b & c \\
  d & e & f \\
  g & i & j \\
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A slightly off-topic question. I have read that `tabu` has some bugs which will not be fixed until the next version. On ctan, the latest version appears to be from 2011, which indicates to be that the 'next version' is not out yet. Will any updates affect my work in the next year or so?

Comment: @GeorgeTian, yes I gather that `tabu` has some issues, and not everyone is a fan. I use it often though and don't have problems. I think it's more or less abandoned by its developer, so I wouldn't hold my breath for updates.