# Use list of ABBREVIATIONS as table in latex

Tags: tables, acronyms

I found it hard to produce such a table in ABBREVIATIONS, is there any suggestions?
like this [image]

Comment: Can't you just type them out? What's the question?

Comment: Unless you want to generate the abbreviation automatically from the name? (note: may not be a good idea anyway in case the abbreviation does not make complete sense)

Comment: [Automatically creating table with borders - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512053/automatically-creating-table-with-borders)

Comment: Although for the style, using another style may be "better" --https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/492175/how-to-generate-list-of-abbreviations-in-latex

Answer (score 2):

Although I wouldn't recommend such a caged style for a list of acronyms, here is how you could achieve it using a combination of `acro` and `nicematrix`. Side note: This solution will only work properly if your list does not exceed the length of a single page.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{acro}
\acsetup{use-id-as-short}

\DeclareAcronym{AA}{long = Alpha Acids}
\DeclareAcronym{ABV}{long = Alcohol By Volume}
\DeclareAcronym{DMS}{long = Dimethyl Sulfide}


\NewAcroTemplate[list]{customtable}
  {
    \acronymsmapF
      { \AcroAddRow{\acrowrite {short}&\acrowrite {list}\\} }
      { \AcroRerun }  
    \acroheading
    \acropreamble
    \par \noindent
    \begin{NiceTabularX}{\linewidth}{lX}[hvlines, cell-space-limits=3pt]
      \AcronymTable
    \end{NiceTabularX}
  }

\begin{document}

\acuseall

\printacronyms[sort=true, template=customtable]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you so much !!!